# .htaccess rewrite to remove extension and query string and make into folder structure but if page doesn't exist send to another page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have the an .htaccess (included below) which works wonderfully.  It takes a user to the content.php page and shows them the page that is stored in the database.  However, there are some pages which required me to hardcode and thus are listed with the .php extension.  Is there any way to add a rewrite rule that will allow me to remove the extension and send the query string as directories.

> **Example**
>
> Current: http://www.example.com/dashboard.php?ax=clients&do=save&miscthirdparam=doitnow
>
> To: http://www.example.com/dashboard/clients/save/doitnow/

However, if the dashboard.php page doesn't exist, then just send it to content.php as it does now to check if there is a page in the database to display?  (I have an Error 404 show if there is no page in the db).

**My Current .htaccess **

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/(.*)$ /content.php?url=$1/$2 [L]
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /content.php?err=404
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**RewriteCond backreference**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). We can extract the first URL path, and find out if the php file exists. Given your example, we extract `dashboard` and check if `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dashboard.php` file exists. If so, rewrite the url with specified paramaters. The regex `[^/]*` matches all characters except followed by forward slash `/`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]*)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(/([^/]*))?(/([^/]*))?(/([^/]*))? /$1.php?ax=$3&do=$5&miscthirdparam=$7 [L]
```

Comment: Where would this go so that if the file doesn't exist it falls back onto content.php?  I've tried placing it in different places but doesn't seem to work anywhere. :)

Comment: you can paste just before the first `RewriteCond`

Comment: I have done that however when I try to visit say www.example.com/dashboard/ which should go to www.example.com/dashboard.php, it just goes to /content.php and displays the 404 because the page isn't in the database.

Comment: just update the rule, previously all three parameters `ax` `do` `miscthirdparam` are required, and now changes to optional