# After extension is removed, if file doesn't exist, send to a particular page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My question is somewhat similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029681/htaccess-rewrite-to-remove-extension-and-query-string-and-make-into-folder-stru) but not exactly and I can't understand it enough to adapt it to my needs.

I have this htaccess rule to remove file extensions which works well

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

So `/somepage` refers to `/somepage.php`. I now need a sort of fallback to it incase `somepage.php` doesn't exist.

In which case `/somepage` would rewrite to `/catchall.php?link=somepage` which can handle the requests. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current rule is adding `.php` extension blindly without checking existence of matching `.php` file. You can tweak your rule to check for presence of `.php` file and then only add `.php`. When a matching `.php` file doesn't exist then we can rewrite to `/catchall.php`.

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# add .php extension only if a matching .php file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# If URI is still not pointing to a valid file/directory
# then rewrite to /catchall.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ catchall.php?link=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Close but the extension removal code sort of doesn't work right and I think its because of `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. I'm currently testing it on localhost and my full url is `localhost/website/somepage` and it should resolve to `localhost/website/somepage.php` if the page exists. I think it might be resolving to `localhost/somepage.php`. Can you make it relative, so to speak?

Comment: ok try my updated code now

Comment: Nice Answer @Anubhava sir ++